# Javascript indexOf not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test whether a value already exists in an array.

In this case, the value of "node1" does not change. both arrays are identical.

However, the same node is added to the array twice, despite the indexOf(node1) test.
http://jsfiddle.net/v9yxj5hm/2/

```
var tree_rows = []; 

var node1 = ['Workplace','Revenue Overall',0];  
if (tree_rows.indexOf(node1) == -1){ tree_rows.push(node1); } 

node1 = ['Workplace','Revenue Overall',0]; 
if (tree_rows.indexOf(node1) == -1){ tree_rows.push(node1); } 

alert(tree_rows)
```

Comment: Two arrays are two different objects. `[] != []`. You need to loop, and compare **each** item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.indexOf()` method compares as if it were using the `===` strict equality operator. No two distinct arrays are equal to each other under those conditions.

When you use array (or, for that matter, object) literal expressions to create objects, you get distinct individual objects. The fact that one literal expression looks exactly like another doesn't mean they share identity.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any built in function to perform non strict equality comparisons for arrays?

Comment: @corycorycory no, if you want to compare arrays you have to implement your own approach to doing it. A general-purpose "deep compare" operation is really hard to define for a language like JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The second use of declaration

```
node1 = ['Workplace','Revenue Overall',0];
```

when node1 already existed created a new entry in the lexical environment for node1. As a result, the check for `indexOf` will not find a previous value for that entry. This ends with `node1` being placed in the array a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare whether each item in `node1` is in `tree_rows`. Maybe you want this?

```
var tree_rows = []; 

var node1 = ['Workplace','Revenue Overall',0];  
for (i in node1) { if (tree_rows.indexOf(node1[i]) == -1){ tree_rows.push(node1[i]); }} 

node1 = ['Workplace','Revenue Overall',0]; 
for (i in node1) { if (tree_rows.indexOf(node1[i]) == -1){ tree_rows.push(node1[i]); }}

alert(tree_rows)
```